# How far back in time can FQL query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How far back in time can query my stream using FQL (Facebook Query Language)? Is it possible to trace all the way back to my first post on Facebook?

Comment: Why don't try and see yourself?

Comment: I tried but I can only go as far as 4 months back. Here is the query I use: 'SELECT created_time, attachment, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = ".$me['id']." and actor_id=".$me['id']." limit 1000'

Comment: I didn't see this comment before I posted, but when I did mine (using FacebookSDK C#) limit 1000 was able to return all my posts back to 2007

Comment: I was wrong, it only goes back about 500 or so posts. Maybe they'll up the limit again in the future

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked only 5,000 most recent records were available (for most queries). That is you can only see latest 5,000 wall posts, the rest doesn't exist for you no matter what FQL parameters you pass.

Comment: I don't think I have more than 5000. but it won't return anything older than 4 months. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer can help:

[How far back in time can you go with the Facebook API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062026/how-far-back-in-time-can-you-go-with-the-facebook-api/4097405#4097405)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you, or if it goes along with serg's answer, but I just did a query like this `SELECT source_id,message,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() limit 1000"` and I was able to get what appears to be all of mine. It only returned 440...maybe I'm not that popular after all...

Comment: I have just realized that this only goes back about 2 years.